# Cannot install Ubuntu along with Windows 8 in Sony Vaio

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have created a Live USB by following the steps provided in the Ubuntu page.

But when I restart by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> key it asks me to choose an option. I select EFI USB, but then it starts Windows 8.

I have gone through [this link](http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/).

Please Help.

Comment: Shutdown your computer then Connect your USB flash drive and press `ASSIST` button then select `USB/DVD ...` or something like this. If it's not boot from USB, maybe your USB flash drive(formated as FAT32) isn't bootable.

Comment: To check if your USB is bootable, you could use Hyper-V (standard with Win8), VirtualBox or VMWare Player and try to create a virtual machine from your USB stick... if that doesn't work, you know the problem is with your USB stick.

Comment: thx @KasiyA will try ur suggestion and will come back to you, if any problem faced.

Answer (score 1):

@user3180373

I had similar issue when I configured the my laptop to dual boot. I used a Live CD. Below are some links that helped configure the system.

- [DUAL boot issues with windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399110/dual-boot-issues-with-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
- [Dual boot with Windows 8.1 on Toshiba Satellite](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418292/dual-boot-with-windows-8-1-on-toshiba-sattelite)